# Same origin policy seemingly not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to understand the same origin policy in detail. To this end i tried to see how it worked with code (i'm a total noob in web development) so i started a Flask server and created a domain `local.com` and a subdomain `store.local.com`. Then in the `store.html` page of the subdomain i created an `iframe` with `src=http://local.com` - without modifying the `document.domain` property in any way as read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Now from what i had read, i tought this would fail, but instead it correctly shows the content of the super domain `index.html` page. I've repeated the experiment hosting the two domains on two different physical computers but that didn't change anything. (I've tried both Firefox and Chrome)

Now i've also tried with with `src=http://google.com` and this does actually get stopped by the SOP. So at the moment i'm kind of in deep confusion, could anyone pls help me make some sense of it? Thanks.

Comment: Is looks to me that the SOP allows access to different sub domains on the same domain.  Where store.local.com is the same domain as local.com whereas google.com is a completely separate domain.

Comment: the same origin policy is slightly different when it comes to iframes. By default it's allowed to *display* the page in the iframe, however the two cannot communicate without cooperating. The page in the iframe can however prevent you from displaying said page in an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFrames are generally exempt from the same origin policy.

However, if you look at the HTTP response headers when you call `http://google.com`, you will see the following header:

```
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
```

This explicitly [tells your browser that it should prevent the page from being displayed across origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

---

[MDN describes this particular behavior:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access)

> Here are some examples of resources which may be embedded cross-origin:
>
> [...]
>
> - Anything with `<frame>` and `<iframe>`. A site can use the `X-Frame-Options` header to prevent this form of cross-origin interaction.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please suggest me how to make a working example of  same origin policy? It's probably an easy thing but how do I actually get javascript on a page to try and access the dom of another?

Comment: The DOM only exists in your browser. You can make an HTTP call to a URL that falls under the SOP and you should encounter the error message you're looking for. Look into [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)!